# a tag disappearing in rendered HTML (using HTL in href property)

Tags: aem, sightly, htl

so I have this piece of HTL

```
<div class="col-lg-6"><a href="${properties.targetURL@context='uri'}" class="black_transparent_button">View all fishes|${properties.targetURL}</a></div>
```

When I view the page (view as published) in my local AEM, this is the rendered HTML

```
<div class="col-lg-6">View all fishes|/content/myhost/en/fishes.html</div>
```

as can be seen, the a tag has disappeared.

As a test, I tried using the relative link directly like this:

I tried with/without context=uri and I get the same issue.

```
<div class="col-lg-6"><a href="/content/myhost/en/fishes.html" class="black_transparent_button">View all fishes</a></div>
```

And the a tag disappeared as well. Using full URL (i.e. http://www.myhost.com/content/myhost/en/fishes.html) **works** fine.

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Thanks

**Edit:** I also tried the second code (the one using relative URL) in our testing environment (in the cloud and hosted by Adobe) and I get the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

This happens, most likely, because your `properties.targetURL` is a malformed URL, and the removal of the `<a>` is most likely due to [antiSammy](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_AntiSamy_Project) which is used in HTL implementation for XSS protection and HTML validation.

Take the following examples (AEM 6.3):

```
<a href="${'https://www.google.com'}">google</a> <!-- google -->
<a href="${'hi'}"></a> <!-- hi -->
<a href="${'https://hello'}"> hello  </a> <!-- hello -->
<a href="${null}"> null </a> <!-- null -->
```

renders:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com">google</a> <!-- google -->
<!-- hi -->
<a href="https://hello"> hello  </a> <!-- hello -->
<a> null </a> <!-- null -->
```

> Note that I'm using HTL expressions `${}` here, not a direct `href="string"` and only HTL expressions are validated.

The one link that was not a correctly formatted url, the `<a>` tag was removed. Also note, that if the expression evaluates to null, the `<a>` is rendered but the `href` is removed per the HTL spec.

Hope this helps.

> PS, you can use [HTL REPL](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/aem-htl-repl) to test this fast without having to setup a component.

Answer (score 1):

Day CQ Link Checker Transformer configuration validates if the URL is valid content resource on a instance, if not complete link tag is removed (Absolute URLs excluded). Following is the snapshot of configuration

[image]

Following could be reasons

1. Relative URL is has valid URL characters but content path is not a valid resource on instance.
2. URL is not a valid resource per [resource resolver mappings](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/deploying/using/resource-mapping.html)

You could verify by `Disable Checking`. If this is working in this case double check URL paths are valid resources or not.